# Why does the second div in my container get tucked?

Tags: html, css

I've tried to find any hint of a similar question to what I have on Stack Overflow to no avail. On a quest to fundamentally understand `float` and `clear`, I've run into an obstacle that doesn't quite make sense to me.

**CSS:**

```
.div1 {
    background-color: red;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.div2 {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 60%;
    height: 600px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.container {
    height: 800px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="div1"></div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Why does the second div have all that space above it? I understand how including `float: left` to `div1` would alleviate the issue because `div2` would then wrap around `div1`, but I fail to understand why the issue exists in the first place. I would appreciate any explanation. Thanks.

Here's a JSFiddle for quick access to see what I'm working with: https://jsfiddle.net/y8gdbzd6/3/

Comment: By "tuck", do you mean the small space between the divs?

Comment: No I understand the space between divs is caused by `display: inline-block`, but rather I'm speaking of the space above the second blue div. Why is that space there? 
EDIT: edited my post to be more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "tuck under", I'm guessing you're referring to the vertical alignment of the two blocks.

When using `display: inline-block`, the [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) property is set to `baseline` by default. This will cause elements of varying height to line up based on the baseline of the parent element.

You're probably expecting the behavior of `vertical-align: top`:

```css
.div1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 60%;
  height: 600px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.container {
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```